# Creating file from BLOB data using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, blob

I am creating file from BLOB data using SQL, file created successfully but not able to open the file. Below is the message appears when trying to open the file,

> We're sorry. We can't open "file_name" because we found a problem with
>   its contents.
>
> Details, The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

I am using BLOB data stored in DB table for creating files using below approach,

```
declare @init int
declare @file varbinary(max) = CONVERT(varbinary(max), N'blob here')
declare @filepath nvarchar(max) = N'c:\Test\file_name.docx'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instace created
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1; 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @file; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @filepath, 2; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources
```

Comment: As a first step, verify `SELECT DATALENGTH(YourBlobColumn)` matches the actual file length. I think we'll need to see your DDL and code to help you more. Is the blob stored as a varbinary(MAX) column?

Comment: Thank you Dan for your reply. Yes, BLOB is stored in varbinary(MAX).

Comment: Where's `blob here` coming from? Take care that if you're copy-pasting stuff from something like Management Studio, you'll be getting the bytes as a hexstring, but by default `CONVERT` simply converts strings using their code points. Write a `SELECT` that actually reads from the table, or supply a style parameter to the `CONVERT` to convert hexstrings (`CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'0x1234', 1)`). Note that a `docx` is just a zipfile under another extension, so examining it with anything that supports zipfiles (including good old Notepad to see if things start with `PK`) can also help.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, instead of copying the BLOB from DB table now I am fetching by using SELECT query. Able to download and open the file. The file corrupt issue is resolved. Thank you for your suggestion.